# How to access claims of other than current user in Microsoft Identity 3

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Microsoft Identity 3. I can access the claims of the current user.
But I can't figure out how to do the same for another user.

For the current user, inside the controller, I can access the claims collection via:

```
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = User.Claims;
```

I can see all the user claims and I can add a claim as follows:

```
var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("role", "manager"));
```

But if I do this:

```
IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
```

"user" has a "Claims" collection but the count is zero and the collection is empty.
How can I access the claims of other than the current user and be able to add and delete claims?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to what I wanted to do turned out to be very easy -- even though I don't fully understand the "why". I can just up-cast IdentityUser to ApplicationUser in the following and it works:

```
IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
// The following will show the current claims:
var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync((ApplicationUser) user);
// The following adds a new claim:
await _userManager.AddClaimAsync((ApplicationUser) user, new Claim("time", "yesterday"));
```