# Pull current users claims from database

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get the currently logged in Users claims (from the database), but everything I try either requires a `ClaimsPrinicpal` or a `User` which I don't seem to have. Ive tried [searching forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2104155.aspx?Accessing%20Claims%20Value%20After%20Login), and [searching SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378724/how-to-access-claims-of-other-than-current-user-in-microsoft-identity-3) with no luck. What am I missing?

```
public IEnumerable<Claim> PullCurrentUserClaims(UserManager<ApplicationUser> u)
{
    return u.;
}
```

Comment: There is an extension method called GetClaims() in the UserManager object. Please refer to the link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151638(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: @ngeksyo that looks perfect, but I don't know how to get the user id of the logged in user

Comment: Have you tried any of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404935/mvc-5-access-claims-identity-user-data?rq=1  Do they all have a blank identity?

Comment: @Rilcon42 based on your method signature there is no parameter userId. If you are under a controller you can use this this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), assuming that you're userId is of type int.